# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request in .netcore

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular6

i have .net core application in development its working fine but when i publish my app and deploy on IIS its show me  below picture Error. i spend 5 6 hours in this issue but not success anyone help me this. why its show this error where i mistake anyone guid me

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
           // app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                   spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

angular.json

```
  {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "ClientApp": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "prefix": "app",
          "schematics": {},
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/ClientApp",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.css",
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ],
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  //"extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [],
                "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets"
                ]
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                  "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "ClientApp-e2e": {
          "root": "e2e/",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "lint": {


       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ClientApp"
}
```

[image: image description]

Comment: Sounds like your IIS process doesn't have correct permissions. What error suggests, is that it is trying to run `mkdir ...` command and it doesn't have the correct permissions to do so. I can't tell you why it wants to create a dir in `c:/windows/...`, but try playing around with the permissions of the IIS process/container/app

Comment: Can you try compiling in vs code instead and see what happens? I’ve seen this before

Comment: yes its successfully build

Comment: this error shows in when i deploy code on IIS

Answer (score 3):

After a day researching this, the solution for me was found here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5238
as pointed by @boonmathew.
The solution was making sure the rootpath in the startup file

```
// In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
   configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
```

matched the output path in angular.json file
 `"outputPath": "dist",`

also since you are seeing that message, if you are using right click publish, make sure to change you deployment setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production

[edit app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f980j.png)

[environment definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7ghT.png)

That's what solved it for me.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

./ statement is missing

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

            ]
```